# Integrating Symfony security and other template utilities with ReactJS

Tags: php, symfony, reactjs

I have working application on symfony with twig template engine. It is very usefull to have `app.request` and `app.user` objects and utils like `is_granted('ROLE_MODER')` in template. Is there way for handling all this in react js? For example for routes i think i could use [FOS JsRouting bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html), but i couldn't find any opportunity how could i access `app` 
object or granting function in react js.

Comment: I think [JSON web tokens](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest4/json-web-token) (https://jwt.io/) will handle that more, especially if you're rendering your templates only in the browser, although your endpoints will, of course, have permissions of some sort.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes, problem if in this example: moderators need to have 'delete' link for posts, and i have no idea how to handle this case.

Comment: You could try out https://github.com/nelsoft-easyshop/react-serverside-renderer

Comment: If it's a SPA built with React, Vue, Backbone or any of the browser-side stuff, look into how they recommend you do that. I would think you control that with module access, but I don't know.

Comment: Not to mention, it's the _server_ that controls whether any data gets saved; whether the button displays or not (obviously, knowing when it should is key but it's not _security_, it's convenience), if someone without permissions clicks on it, the server should reject the request if their JSON web token identifies them as someone without permission.

Comment: @fyrye yeah, and this https://github.com/Limenius/ReactBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: @JaredFarrish seems that easiest way is to rewrite project to nodejs :D

Comment: This is a massive application Symfony/EmberJS, I know, but this should help somewhat to see how they did it here (this can be entirely offline): https://github.com/ilios Also, this is a starter version, maybe easier to follow but I don't know if it handles security: https://github.com/ucsf-ckm/symfony-emberjs-edition

Comment: And the talk I saw given by the Ilios project lead: https://jrjohnson.github.io/slides/2015-10-symfony-api/#1 For example: [_Security via JWT_](https://jrjohnson.github.io/slides/2015-10-symfony-api/#27)

Comment: If you use the JWT approach you can add the symfony user roles to the jwt payload and build your access / grant routines in react on these. That's at least what worked for us in an angular SPA. [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) maybe of help here.

Answer (score 2):

You could struct your application using HATEOAS:

```
https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas
```

and also a REST bundle

```
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html
```

Finally, to keep everything in security you can work with symfony's Voter/or ACL:

```
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html
```

and keep all the control you need.

If you want to tell symfony information to reactjs, just create an endpoint for this. If you want to build a react component that handle with symfony's part, build it using twig.

But I suggest you to consider your symfony part as a REST API. I mean, ... you are just talking with an API. Your ReactJs client should never know that that API is written in Symfony.

Comment: yeah, but question is how to handle security from reactJs

Comment: To handle app element in Reacjs, ... just show app content inside an endpoint called via ReactJs. It's easy.

Comment: and make one more call for each request?

Comment: You want to make in client side same thing you already do in server side ^_^

Comment: No, i'm just looking for most optimal way =)